# Пароль должен содержать как минимум один символ из каждого массива

Tags: php, массивы, password

Подскажите как сделать что бы пароль обязательно содержал как минимум один символ из каждого массива(с буквами, цифрами и символами)?

Есть такой код генератора пароля:

```
<?php

    function gen_password_arrays($length) { 

    $password = "";

    $a1 = array('1', '2','3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0');

    $a2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' );

    $a3 = array('#', '!', "?", "&");

    $arr = array_merge($a1, $a2, $a3); 

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)

    $password .= $arr[mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1)]; 
    return $password;
    }

    echo 'Пароль: '.gen_password_arrays(10);

    ?>
```

Comment: приложите пожалуйста код непосредственно в тело вопроса, чтобы участники сразу видели пример кода. Большая часть участников, не будет вчитываться и при отсутствии кода может просто проигнорировать вопрос. Плюс различные сервисы не всегда доступны и хранят код ограниченное количество времени. А хотелось бы чтобы Ваш вопрос мог помочь не только Вам, но и другим участникам со схожей проблемой. И никто не гарантирует что через пару лет Ваш пример на phpfiddle останется нетронутым. Спасибо за понимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов.
Самый простой - просто гарантировать, что мы работаем со всеми 3мя массивами:

```
//    $arr = array_merge($a1, $a2, $a3); // складываем массивы
    $arrays = [$a1, $a2, $a3];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $arr = $arrays[$i%3];
      $password .= $arr[mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1)]; // берём случайный элемент из массива
    }
    return $password;
```

Второй вариант, как мне кажется более правильный, его сложнее реализовать:
Идея в том, чтобы отслеживать все, что должно быть и если чего-то нет, добавить рандомно ручками.

```
$a3 = array( // массив с символами
    '#', '!', "?", "&"
);
$whatIsUsed = [0, 0, 0];
$arrays = [$a1, $a2, $a3];
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    $sourceArr = mt_rand(0, count($arrays)-1);
    $whatIsUsed[$sourceArr] += 1;
    $arr = $arrays[$sourceArr];
    $password[$i] = $arr[mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1)]; // берём случайный элемент из массива
}
for($i=0;$i<count($arrays); $i++){
    if ($whatIsUsed[$i] == 0){
        $arr = $arrays[$i];
        $item = $arr[mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1)];
        $index = mt_rand(0, $length-1);
        $password[$index] = $item;
    }
}
return implode("",$password);
```

Я не очень силен в php, поэтому немного криво.

Answer (score 1):

**Основные идеи:**

- Для того чтобы сохранить информацию о составе массивов, нам их
  необходимо сохранить, не смешивая между собой.
  При этом нам необходимо выбирать элементы
  из случайных массивов, поэтому решением может быть использование
  двумерного массива.
- Для получения случайного символа нам
  необходимо будет сгенерировать индекс для случайного массива и для
  случайного символа в этом массиве.
- Для того чтобы обеспечить
  наличие как минимум одного символа из каждого массива достаточно
  будет первые n символов (где n - это количество массивов),
  генерировать из массива под индексом n-1.
   
  Для этого можно
  использовать простое условие в цикле `if($i<count($arr))`.
- Для того чтобы символы в пароле стояли в случайном порядке можно их будет
  смешать функцией `shuffle()`, поэтому изначально элементы пароля мы будем хранить не в строке, а в массиве.
- После чего достаточно будет склеить элементы смешанного массива в строку с помощью функции `join()`

**ИТОГ**:

```
<?php
function gen_password_arrays($length) {
    $a1 = array( // массив с цифрами
        '1', '2','3', '4', '5', '6',
        '7', '8', '9', '0'
    );
    $a2 = array( // массив с буквами
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
        'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
        'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
        's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
        'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
        'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
        'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
        'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
        'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
    );
    $a3 = array( // массив с символами
        '#', '!', "?", "&"
    );

    $arr = array($a1, $a2, $a3);
    $passChars = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        if($i < count($arr))
            $arrayIndex = $i;
        else
            $arrayIndex = mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1);

        $charIndex = mt_rand(0, count($arr[$arrayIndex]) - 1);

        $passChars[] = $arr[$arrayIndex][$charIndex];
    }
    shuffle($passChars);
    return join("",$passChars);
}
echo '<strong>Пароль: </strong>'.gen_password_arrays(10);
?>
```